# Turning Lighbox images, into a slideshow

Tags: jquery, image, lightbox

I am creating a website. On this site I am using the same Lightbox script I have used for years. Its simple, loads fast and I have never had complaints. Now, this client want something where you click the image, the larger image pops up in the Lightbox, and you need to be able to cycle left and right.

http://holidaylettingsbulgaria.co.uk/rentone.html

Is there anything I can add to the lightbox script to make this cycle through to the next large image?

You can see the Lightbox script here :-  http://codepen.io/studiowebmedia/pen/kFchr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can add "Next" and "Prev" link and simulate click on next/prev image:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="lightbox">Photo 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="lightbox">Photo 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="lightbox">Photo 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="lightbox">Photo 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="menu" style="display:none;">
  <a href="#" id="prev">&laquo; Prev</a>
  <a href="#" id="next">Next &raquo;</a>
</div>


$('.lightbox').click(function(){
   $('.lightbox').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");

   $('#menu').show();
});
$('#next').click(function(){
    var img_index = $('.lightbox.active').index('.lightbox')+1;

    if($('.lightbox:eq('+img_index+')').size()==0) $('.lightbox:first').click();
    else $('.lightbox:eq('+img_index+')').click();
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    var img_index = $('.lightbox.active').index('.lightbox')-1;

    if(img_index<0) $('.lightbox:last').click();
    else $('.lightbox:eq('+img_index+')').click();
});
```